# How to check if sqlite database file is writable by the web process in my Yii2 application?

Tags: php, database, sqlite, yii2

I am developing an Yii2 application and at times, the Sqlite3 file which I use for database, becomes "read only" (due to other stuff happening on the server) and users are getting nasty PHP exception errors instead of a nicely displayed error message. 
I am trying to use the "beforeSave()" function to check if the databse is writable, but I don't know the best way to check if the web process (www-data) has write access to it.
Anyone any ideas?
I have the following two functions in my base model:

```
    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            // Check if database is writable
            if($this->attemptDBWrite())
                return true;
            else
            {
                \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Database is not writable by the application user');
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And the "attemptDBWrite()" function:

```
    public function attemptDBWrite()
    {
        try {
            $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
            // SOME CODE NEEDED HERE TO CHECK <<<=========
        } catch (\yii\db\Exception $e) {
            \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', var_dump($e));
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define read-only? The disk IO layer, or the SQLite3 concurrency layer?

Comment: It's as simple as the owner is different than "www-data". To either the sqlite file itself or the parent directory

Comment: http://php.net/is-writable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public function attemptDBWrite()
    {
        try {
            $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
            if (is_writable($database_source_path)) {
                return false;
              }
        } catch (\yii\db\Exception $e) {
            \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', var_dump($e));
            return false;
        }
    }
```

> $database_source_path -  is path of sqlite database file

Comment: Wow, that was easy! :) I didn't know there was such PHP function.